# How to display (or replicate) Activity Publisher without Activity Feed?

Tags: lightning-experience, activities, lightning-quickaction

The standard Activity lightning component available in Lightning App Builder is composed of a "publisher" section which displays Quick Actions (based on the "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions" section of the page layout assigned to the current user) as well as an activity history of related records.  Is there any way to achieve the publisher portion of the page without the history section?  In the screenshot below, I'd like to keep (or replicate) the section in green without the section in red:

[image]

The standard component is not configurable.  I'm willing to "replicate" the publisher by manually setting up the tabs (Log a Call, New Task, New Event, and Email - I don't need to support any other quick actions) either in App Builder or a custom component, but I don't want to manually recreate the editors, especially the Email editor.  Is there any way to insert a specific quick action, either into the App Builder visual editor, or into a custom component?  Any other workaround I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest one thing if you cannot achieve this by `configuration`.
Create a **static Resource**. Create a `css` file with this css (May change, you just need to inspect, but most likely to remain same, but inspect only for the `timeline`)

```
.activityPanel .skip-timeline-wrapper{
    display: none
}
```

Create a Aura Component like this and just place call your CSS from static resource.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" controller="AwSnap"
                access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.TestAppName + '/CSS/style.css'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Edit page, and place your component at the end of you page, as it does not have a document it wont show, but the css will do its work.

Though I dont have any buttons `Task` , `call` etc but it works:

**Before CSS**:

[image]

**After CSS**:

[image]